# Second Frobenius-Schur indicator and near-group categories G+|G|

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, frobenius-schur-indicator

A near-group category $G+m$ is a (spherical) fusion category whose simple objects are given by the element $g$ of the finite group $G$, plus one extra simple object $y$, with Grothendieck ring as follows:

- $x_{g}x_{g'} = x_{gg'}$,
- $x_gy=yx_g = y$,
- $y^2 = my+\sum_{g \in G}x_g$.

The notion of near-group category was introduced in 2000 by Masaki Izumi (see [1](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1782145), [2](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1832764), [3](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3635673)), and for a given finite group $G$, not every integer $m$ is possible, for example $C_3+0$ exists but $C_3+1$ does not (where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$).

The k-th Frobenius-Schur indicator of a (complex) character $\chi$ of $G$ is defined as:
$$ \nu_k(\chi):=\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^k) $$
When $\chi$ is irreducible and $k=2$, then $\nu_2(\chi)$ can only be $0$, $-1$ or $+1$. It is nonzero iff the underlying representation $V$ is self-adjoint, and $-1$ iff $V$ is symplectic. Now, Rep($G$) is a pivotal fusion category (in fact, unitary) and the notion of Frobenius-Schur indicator was extended to every pivotal fusion category in 2007 by Siu-Hung Ng and Peter Schauenburg (see [4](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2381536)), and as before the second Frobenius-Schur indicator of a simple object can only be $0$, $-1$ or $+1$.

The Frobenius-Schur indicators are not determined by the Grothendieck ring, for example, Rep$(D_4)$ and Rep($Q_8$) are two different near-group fusion categories $C_2^2+0$, where $\nu_2(y) = 1$ for the first and $-1$ for the second.

**Question**: Is it true that $\nu_2(y)=1$ for a near-group category $C_n + n$?

[This paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4044867) of Henry Tucker is about the Frobenius-Schur indicators for near-group (and Haagerup-Izumi) fusion categories, and Proposition 4.5 provides a formula for $\nu_r(y)$ for a near-group category $G + |G|$. I hope that this formula can help to answer the above question (I already asked Henry by email few days ago). I already know that it is true if $n$ is odd, because then $y<y^2$ with an odd multiplicity (in fact, for every spherical fusion category with simple objects $a,b$ such that $a$ is self-adjoint and $a < bb^*$ with odd multiplicity, then $\nu_2(a) = 1$).

Comment: If Henry doesn’t know, the odds of someone else here knowing is quite small.